# Script fails to see running as root

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is my root check code. If does not pass don't run the script as you need root. Not sure as to what is going wrong here:

```
if [ "whoami &2>/dev/null" != "root" ] && [ "id -un &2>/dev/null" != "root" ] ; then
    $BIN_ECHO " must be root to run this script "
    exit 1
else
    $BIN_ECHO -e " permission check passed "
fi
```

after running i get:

```
must be root to run this script
[root@localhost ~]# whoami
root
[root@localhost ~]# id -un
root
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing the strings containing the commands to "root". [This is not what you want](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

```
if [ "$(whoami &2>/dev/null)" != "root" ] && ...
```

Answer (score 8):

"whoami" is a string of characters.

`whoami` is the output of a command.

Answer (score 2):

`"whoami &2>/dev/null"` and `"id -un &2>/dev/null"` are just strings, they are not running the commands.  Use: `"$(whoami &2>/dev/null)"` and `"$(id -un &2>/dev/null)"` instead.